# Using Imagemagick command in python

Tags: python, imagemagick

I am working on Windows 7 32 Bit and I have installed the ImageMagick-7.0.10-62-Q16-x86-static.exe from this link https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php
Also I have added the path to the environment variables
When trying this line in cmd or powershell, the line is working well

```
magick convert Output.png -resize 400x260 -density 300 -quality 100 Temp.jpg
```

But when trying the following code

```
import os
sTemp = 'Temp.jpg'
command = 'magick convert {} -resize 400x260 -density 300 -quality 100 {}'.format('Output.png', sTemp)
os.system(command)
```

I got 1 as output and I didn't get the desired Temp.jpg output.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't use `magick convert ...` - it is just `magick` without `convert` unless you want some very specific behaviour. There is no point setting `-density` here either, or `-quality 100` - if you want lossless, just use PNG as your output format. As regards why it didn't work, try running `magick -version` to see if that works as a first test.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have Windows 10 64 Bit at home and the code is working well without any problems. The problem occurs with the PC at work which has Windows 7 32 Bit. Is there a relationship between the error and the OS used?

Comment: At the download page there are two different versions for 32bit and 64 bit and for each version there is static and dll (Which is better)? I am using static.